# Date string wont convert to timestamp

Tags: php, postgresql, timestamp, string-conversion

I am trying to grab any record with a `ctime` of today. For some reaosn, &tomorrow and &yesterday do not have any values. If I remove `strtotime()` their values are string representations of the date derived from `mktime`. What am I doing wrong with `strtotime`?

PHP:

```
public function fetchToday()
{
    $tomorrow  = strtotime(mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m")  , date("d")+1, date("Y")));
    $yesterday  = strtotime(mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m")  , date("d")-1, date("Y")));      
    $q = "SELECT * FROM $this->_table WHERE ctime < $tomorrow AND ctime > $yesterday";      
    return $this->fetchBySelect($q);
}
```

Error:

`ModelFactory - 'ERROR: syntax error at or near "AND"
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM motd WHERE ctime < AND ctime >`

PostrgeSQL table field:

`ctime timestamp(0) with time zone`

Query:

`SELECT * FROM motd WHERE ctime < 1372402800 AND ctime > 1372230000;`

`

Comment: that's what the op is asking about - why they're not getting values for `$tomorrow` and `$yesterday`

Comment: Ah, sorry. Well, the tag was "postgresql", so I assumed that he sees it as Pg issue. My bad, removed the irrelevant/wrong comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All answers so far focus on php side, but on the other hand, I would say that the proper solution is to use PostgreSQL features, and change the php code to:

```
public function fetchToday()
{
    $q = "SELECT * FROM $this->_table WHERE ctime < 'tomorrow'::timestamptz AND ctime > 'yesterday'::timestamptz;";      
    return $this->fetchBySelect($q);
}
```

Comment: pg_query(): Query failed: ERROR: cannot cast type integer to timestamp with time zone LINE 1: SELECT * FROM motd WHERE ctime < 1372402800::timestamptz AND...

Comment: nm that worked. ty. forgot to change $tomorrow and $today to 'tomrrow' and 'today'. Feel like explaining why that works? point me to reference? ty again.

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-SPECIAL-TABLE has all the info.

Answer (score 3):

Why not just:

```
$tomorrow  = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day")); // sets tomorrow = 2013-06-28
$yesterday  = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("-1 day")); // sets tomorrow = 2013-06-26
```

This is assuming your ctime column is a MySQL datestamp.  If it's a unix timestamp then:

```
$tomorrow  = strtotime("+1 day");
$yesterday  = strtotime("-1 day");
```

Since strtotime converts a param to a unix timestamp.  Your code is redundant using both strtotime and mktime.

EDIT: Based on previous posts, looks like your ctime column is a unix timestamp, so my second example is the way to go.  `strtotime("+1 day")` will return an int representing the unix timestamp of `NOW + 1` Day, and reverse for `-1 Day`.

Answer (score 2):

Using `strtotime` on the return value of `mktime` makes no sense. Both functions return a Unix timestamp, so use one or the other. I suggest [`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) because it is simple to use:

```
$tomorrow  = strtotime('tomorrow');
$yesterday = strtotime('yesterday');
```

Each of these returns the timestamp corresponding to the midnight before the day begins, which looks like what you want.

Comment: mktime is not giving me a timestamp. thats my problem. its giving me a string.

Answer (score 1):

I think there are errors in these statements, so they are producing empty strings and make query to fail.

```
$tomorrow  = strtotime(mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m")  , date("d")+1, date("Y")));
$yesterday  = strtotime(mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m")  , date("d")-1, date("Y")));
```

The mktime() returns unix timestamp and you don't need to use strtime().

It depends how you store data in your database. If they are kept as TIMESTAMP, just omit strtotime.

If you keep them as ISO like "YYYY-MM-DD" use date() only.

Answer (score 1):

```
public function fetchToday()
{
    $tomorrow = strtotime("+1 day", strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"))); 
    $yesterday= strtotime("-1 day", strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"))); 
    $q = "SELECT * FROM ".$this->_table." WHERE ctime < ".$tomorrow." AND ctime > ".$yesterday;      
    return $this->fetchBySelect($q);
}
```